# How can I declare all Sphinx delta indexes, from within the sphinx.yml file?

Tags: indexing, thinking-sphinx, delta

Instead of repeating this line in every model file:

```
set_property :delta => true
```

... I would like to declare all delta indexing from the /config/sphinx.yml file, something like this:

```
delta:
  model1: true
  model2: true
  model3: true
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be abrupt, but no, that's not possible. The only place to set delta indices is within each index definition.

Comment: Seems like a natural thing to do. What is the technical reason, for allowing this functionality, perhaps in the next release?

Comment: Can you clarify why you'd rather have this setting in the YAML file, rather than in each index?

Comment: Not saying it's an inherently bad idea, just trying to grasp why it'd be useful. I've never had anyone suggest the idea before. Also, happy to continue this conversation via email if you'd prefer that medium.

Comment: We would like to keep all "universal" settings in one config file, vs spread out across multiple models. Only code unique to a specific model, belongs in that model class. DRY ...

Comment: I guess it depends on what you consider to be universal settings. In TS v3 I've shifted index definitions into their own file - both to enable cleaner loading of them, but to detach them a little more from the models. However, the delta setting is still strongly tied to each index, because it is, at heart, stating that that index should be duplicated (and slightly modified).

Comment: For us, 'delta' indexes are used on all models used with Sphinx, not a subset. For example, I would not delta some models, and not others. That's what I consider 'universal'.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. What I'd probably add is a `default_delta` option, which can be a boolean, or a string that holds a class name. If you want to add an issue to Thinking Sphinx for this - or even submit a patch - that'd be great.

Comment: Ah, that's the old repo - can you add it to pat/thinking-sphinx as well? :)